# Cycling through contents of array issue

Tags: c#

I am using an int array to hold a long list of integers.  For each element of this array I want to check if it is 1, if so do stuff relevant to 1 only, else if it is a 2, do other stuff relevant to 2, and so forth for each value stored in the array.  I came up with the code below but it isn't working as expected, is there something I am missing? What is happening is that only the first value of the array is being considered.

```
int[] variable1 = MyClass1.ArrayWorkings();
foreach (int i in variable1)
{ 
    if (variable1[i] == 1)
    {
        // arbitrary stuff
    }
    else if (variable1[i] ==2)
    {
        //arbitrary stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to do something that doesn't make sense.  To see how it works, take a simple example, an array with values:  9, 4, 1.

If you try to run your code on this sample array, you'll get an error:

```
foreach (int i in variable1)
{ 
    if (variable1[i] == 1)   // the item i is 9.  
                             // But variable[i] means, get the value at position #9 in the array
                             // Since there are only 3 items in the array, you get an Out Of Range Exception
    {
        // arbitrary stuff
    }
{
```

Instead, this is what you need:

```
foreach (int i in variable1)  // i will be 9, then 4, then 1)
{ 
    if (i == 1)   
    {
        // arbitrary stuff
    }
    // ... etc
}
```

The alternative is to use a **for** loop, which would give you the indices 0, 1, and 2, like this:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<=variable1.Length ; i++)   // i will be 0, 1, 2
                                            // variable[i] will be 9, 4, 1
{
    if (variable1[i] == 1) 
    { 
        // stuff
    }

    // ... etc
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, however after changing the code (for (int i=0 ; i<=variable1.Length ; i++)
) it is still only considering the first element

Comment: @user1166981 The first element will only be considered if either a. the first condition is always true, or b. you stop the iteration using *break* or *return*

Comment: If I have 10 items in the array {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1}, the last code example you postede should evaluate each element right? So if I had the logic under each if statement MyVariable = MyVariable + i; Should the total come to 19 or 2?

Comment: @user1166981 should come to 19, it seems.  Something else must be going on; post the code maybe?

Comment: ok, should I just update my original post and show reason in the edit box?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13030/discussion-between-dbaseman-and-user1166981)

Answer (score 8):

The `i` in your `foreach` loop holds the actual element value from the array in each iteration, not the index. In your particular code sample, your array probably holds only zeroes, which is why you're only getting the first element (you're always using index `0`). **Hence, you should check `i` rather than `variable1[i]`.**

If you are going to check against various integer constants, a `switch` expression is more suitable, BTW:

```
foreach (int i in variable1) {
    switch (i) {
        case 1:
            // arbitrary stuff
            break;
        case 2:
            // arbitrary stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

`switch`/`case` saves you some writing; if you ever pull your values from anywhere else than from `i`, you can simply change the `(i)` part in the `switch` statement, and moreover, `switch` might be evaluated by the compiler more efficiently than the chained `if`-`else` statements.

**Note:** You will not be able to directly change array values in the `foreach` loop, as you cannot assign anything to `i`. If you need to assign new array values, you'll have to

- count yourself with an additional variable while still using `foreach` or
- use another loop such as `for` and retrieve the item at the current index yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Write like this instead:

```
foreach (int i in variable1) {
    if (i == 1) {
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The `i` you fetched is not the index but the value. So check `i` with 1 or 2.

If you were using for loop then your inner code would have worked perfectly.

```
int[] variable1 = MyClass1.ArrayWorkings();
foreach (int i in variable1)
{ 
    switch(i)
    {
        case 1: 
            // arbitrary stuff
        break;
        case 2: 
            //arbitrary stuff
        break;
    }
}
```

Try using switch case. Much faster than normal if-else.